# reportviewer issues for hosted application

Tags: asp.net, ssrs-2008

I have a web application which need to access ssrs reports hosted in reporting server.I created a aspx page with report viewer control and was supplying the report url dynamically..
This was working fine when i was debugig the application in vs2008.

But when i published the page several problem showed up..

1. it is identifying the report and showing the proper report input parameter but when i am   clicking the view report option its showing 404 error of IIS server.

2.Calender control for datetime input field is also not working..

please help me if anyone knows the reason..

Answer (score 0):

This was a serious problem..i don't think many people faced it yet..But for future this is the solution..

1) Go to IIS manager.
2) Under IIS area,Double-click on Handler Mappings icon.
At the Action pane on your right, click on Add Managed Handler.
At the Add Managed Handler dialog, enter the following:

```
Request path: Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd
Type: Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler
Name: Reserved-ReportViewerWebControl-axd
```

Click OK.
now run your application again..